# Update query in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have to update a row in the database and writing this

```
var o_voto_foto = {
    Profilo: profilo,
    Foto: data.id_foto_votata,
    punteggio: data.voto,
};

connection.query('UPDATE prof_voto_foto SET ? WHERE profilo_id = :Profilo AND foto_id = :Foto',o_voto_foto, function(error, rows) {
    if (error) {
        var err = "Error on UPDATE 'votoFotoFancybox': " + error;
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
    connection.end();

    callback();

});
```

but I get a syntax error.
however, if the query is done with this syntax

```
connection.query('UPDATE prof_voto_foto SET punteggio = '+data.voto+' WHERE profilo_id = '+profilo+' AND foto_id = '+data.id_foto_votata,function(error, rows) {
```

I use this external library
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Comment: "but I get a syntax error" — **what** syntax error do you get?

Comment: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':Profilo AND foto_id = :Foto' at line 1

Answer (score 3):

Doing this will definitely work:

```
var o_voto_foto = {
    Profilo: profilo,
    Foto: data.id_foto_votata,
    punteggio: data.voto,
};

var params = [o_voto_foto.punteggio, o_voto_foto.Profilo, o_voto_foto.Foto ];

connection.query('UPDATE prof_voto_foto SET punteggio = ? WHERE profilo_id = ? AND foto_id = ? ', params, function(error, rows) {
```

Replacing the parameters in the query starting with a colon which match entries in the parameter object will only work if you register a Custom queryFormat. See the example below. You can't mix ? and parameters starting with a colon.

```
connection.config.queryFormat = function (query, values) {
  if (!values) return query;
  return query.replace(/\:(\w+)/g, function (txt, key) {
    if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return this.escape(values[key]);
    }
    return txt;
  }.bind(this));
};

var params2 = {
punteggio : '',
profilo_id : '',
photo_id : ''
};

connection.query('UPDATE prof_voto_foto SET punteggio = :punteggio WHERE profilo_id = :profilo_id AND foto_id = :photo_id ', params2, function(error, rows) {
```

Comment: That's exactly what the ? will do.

Comment: connection.query('UPDATE prof_voto_foto SET punteggio = ?, created = ? WHERE profilo_id = ? AND foto_id = ?', [ data.voto, created, profilo, data.id_foto_votata ], function(error, rows) {

Comment: @Barno did you get it working now? I suppose the query you posted is working. If not what error are you getting now?

Answer (score 0):

o_voto_foto is an object.  The escape looks for an array.  Try using [o_voto_foto]

Comment: dosen't works, same error i try like 

connection.query('UPDATE prof_voto_foto SET punteggio = :punteggio WHERE profilo_id = :Profilo AND foto_id = :Foto',[o_voto_foto]